# Accessing MediaPlayer in Background Agent in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to capture the current playing track in the Zune music player, in my Background Agent app. Looking at the [Unsupported APIs for Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) page on MSDN, all of XNA is not supported - which means I can't use XNA's `Media.MediaPlayer`. Is there any workaround or solution for this?

Comment: Well, this app is doing just this - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/wp-fm/dda6e711-caa9-43af-a4b1-f2183df1ce49

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

There is currently no way to access anything other than the tracks which you are playing in a BackgroundAudioPlayer agent.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no way to access anything other than THE track (not tracks) that the background audio player is playing.  There is no concept of a playlist exposed by the BAP singleton, which apparently is the source for much frustration with this component.  You have to resort to IsolatedStorage or some other hack to feed the BAP a playlist.